# Pi 3 is connected to internet, can't ssh or ping

Tags: pi-3, wifi, raspbian-stretch

The follow problem has been occurring for 2 weeks with my Pi 3 (Pi, SD card, power supply are all brand new).

After configuring, I boot up my Pi (stretch), it connects to the internet, I am able to ping and SSH in, everything is great. I am feeding multiple ads-b sites automatically.

After a certain amount of time (varies between 3 days to 4 hours) the Pi will be unreachable via ping or SSH. The strange thing is that it keeps feeding to the ADS-B sites. So I know it's online and transmitting data.

I've tried certain scripts that attempt to detect if wlan0 is up/down and reconnect but I later learned ifup was deprecated, invalidating those attempts (I haven't been able to find a new suitable script) that doesn't force a reboot.

Thanks

Comment: when you do reboot, check the system logs for any clue as to what is happening

Comment: Have you used `/etc/network/interaces` to configure your network? If so, do you configure `dhcpcd` accordingly?

Comment: It could simply be the IP address changing after a while if it's dynamically assigned by DHCP. Not clear if we are talking about local or WAN IP address. Are you pinging/SSHing from your ocal network or remotely ?

Comment: @JaromandaX what am I looking for specifically in the logs? I'm currently looking using `dmesg` and `/var/log/messages`

I just had a pretty good run of 10 days uptime, I just noticed if I SSH into the Pi and leave my connection by closing my laptop or just letting it sit overnight, the session drops at some point -- that is when I lose the ability to connect back or find it on my network (even though it is still feeding).

Comment: I'd be looking at other log files in /var/log - looking for anything that may provide a clue to what is happening

Comment: @JaromandaX I just was locked out again (even though it's online feeding) I unplugged and replugged the power for a fresh boot, I looked though a few log files: daemon.log, syslog, kern.log, messages -- but nothing caught my eye -- I'm also not entirely sure what I would see, it's still connected to the internet, just inaccessible via ping/ssh -- I may buy a wifi extender and hardwire into that -- seems like ethernet is the only method that doesn't have issues.